# How to use Switch with a nested TabView?

Tags: user-interface

Good morning everyone.
I am making a menu with multiple options using TabView and Switch, however, there are also sub-options so I needed to use nested TabView, but the problem is with Swith that it no longer works correctly. Thanks for your help.
The sample code is the following:

```
Manipulate[tick;  
               Dynamic@Switch[
                              tabNumber, 
                              tab1, Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
                              tab2, Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], 
                              tab3, Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}],
                              tab4, Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
                              tab5, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
                              tab6, Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
                              ], 
               TabView[
                       {
                        "1 N1" -> Column[tabNumber = tab1; {Row[{"1 N1 selected"}]}], 
                        "2 N1" -> Column[tabNumber = tab2; {Row[{"2 N1 selected"}]}], 
                        "3 N1" -> Column[tabNumber = tab3; {Row[{"3 N1 selected"}]}],
                        "4 N1" -> TabView[
                                      {
                                       "1 N2" -> Column[tabNumber = tab4; {Row[{"1 N2 selected"}]}], 
                                       "2 N2" -> Column[tabNumber = tab5; {Row[{"2 N2 selected"}]}], 
                                       "3 N2" -> Column[tabNumber = tab6; {Row[{"3 N2 selected"}]}]
                                       }, Dynamic@tabNumber]
                        }, Dynamic@tabNumber], 
              {{tick, False}, None}, 
              {{tabNumber, 1},None}, 
              {{tab1, 1}, None}, 
              {{tab2, 2}, None}, 
              {{tab3, 3}, None}, 
              {{tab4, 4}, None},
              {{tab5, 5}, None},
              {{tab6, 6}, None},
              TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left
          ]
```

Comment: You need a `Dynamic` on `"4 N1"` too

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, could you provide a little more detail?